# Getting \n in a string when adding it to email

Tags: python, smtplib

Trying to add a string that I created before from excel using this code

```
data = interface.df
data1 = data.drop_duplicates(subset=["Ref/Lic Nr"], keep="first")
cr = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns= ['Carrier'])
rf = pd.DataFrame(data1,columns= ['Ref/Lic Nr'])
amtg = data1.loc[data1.Carrier=='AMTG', 'Ref/Lic Nr']
amtg1=(amtg.to_string(index=False, header=False))
```

And then in entering it to this code

```
import smtplib
import carriers
gmail_user = 'asgsgasgasg@gmail.com'
gmail_password = 'wqrqwgqwgqwb'

sent_from = gmail_user
if len(carriers.amtg) > 0:   
    to = ['afasgaswrl@gmail.com']
    subject = 'updates'
    body = " Good morning, Can we get updates for: ", carriers.amtg1
else:
     pass

email_text = """\
From: %s
To: %s
Subject: %s

%s
""" % (sent_from, ", ".join(to), subject, body)

try:
    server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.gmail.com', 465)
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(gmail_user, gmail_password)
    server.sendmail(sent_from, to, email_text)
    server.close()

    print ('Email sent!')
except:
    print ('Something went wrong...')
```

But when I receive the info I get values like *CNG41383874\n  CNG41383875\n* instead of:

CNG41383874

CNG41383875

[image: Email that i receive]

Comment: You could always use the rstrip method on the string, like this: `amtg1.rstrip("\\n")`. Use \\ to escape the backslash, plus this way n doesn't form a  newline either.

Comment: Are you getting any error? Because the only thing which you're talking about is that when you receive the info, you get the raw string with newline character `\n` instead of formatted text.

Comment: @Green05 tried that but still somehow receive it wrong. Added image of the email i get.

Comment: @MyWork Hi, yeah im getting raw string not formated text and format is highly important it this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is here:

```
body = " Good morning, Can we get updates for: ", carriers.amtg1
```

That sets the `body` to a `tuple` of strings, not one long string, and when it's formatted into the `email_text` variable, it puts in the `str` form of the `tuple`, which is the `repr` of its components (and the `repr` of a `str` with newlines will display the escape, not the raw newline character). To make it work, concatenate the strings into a single string:

```
body = " Good morning, Can we get updates for: " + carriers.amtg1
```

This will format the normal `str` form into `email_text` directly, not multiple `repr`s, preventing this issue.

Comment: OMG mate , just realized how stupid i was i spend hours trying to fix it)
Thanks )